# In a perl module, is a semicolon required after a sub function?

Tags: perl, module

I am writing code for work and have run into an interesting issue. I have searched my go-to resources on the topic and have not found a clear answer.

When writing a sub function in a Perl module, is a semicolon required after the closing brace?

As in:

```
sub printFoo {

print "foo";

};
```

Is this somehow different than a sub function in a regular Perl script?

When I use the above function in a module without the semicolon I get an error referencing an "undefined subroutine."

I feel confident that in the past I have used similar pieces of code without the semicolon following the closing brace but now I am no longer positive.

A push in the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're writing anonymous function, then you need semicolon, ie.

```
my $func = sub {
   print "foo";
};
```

As for plain functions, semicolon is not required, in fact parser works with:

```
perl -MO=Deparse semi
sub printFoo {
    print 'foo';
}
```

-

```
cat semi
sub printFoo {

print "foo";

};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem seems to have *magically* disappeared on its own. I believe it may have had to do with a database driver and in the end I think I may have miss-attributed the error to the semicolon when it was in fact something else. However, this answer was informative and answered the question as asked. So, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon is not required and won't affect anything.

Are you getting "undefined subroutine" when calling the sub from the same module's code, or from the main program that uses the module?

If the latter, it's likely because you didn't export the sub's name.